# Discord.py check if channel in category

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So, I am creating a command where the bot will check if the command is run in a specific category. If it is, then the bot will proceed with the command. If it is not, the bot will say 'not allowed'. How do I do that?

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you want to do?

Comment: I want to check if the channel is in a specific category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TextChannel has the [category_id](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=category#discord.TextChannel.category_id)
attribute, use it to get the id of the category the channel is currently in, you can then use [get_channel](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_channel#discord.Client.get_channel) to get the category channel you can then match discord.CategoryChannel.name which represents the category name with an string of yours.